# Create SQL query that gets data from several tables WHEN ID is in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a news feed and from previous questions have found the simplest way to execute it but do not know what kind of query I should be making in SQL.

I have a table titled artists that has the members ID, artist name and url to their page, all need to be retrieved. If an ID is not in this table it should not be included in the output of the statement.

I have several tables with similar structures such as tracks, status and news. There are more but we'll stick to those three for this question and I can add more late on. In these tables is the ID among other things and I shall provide these later.

The third table is one titled events. Data is inserted in here via a trigger AFTER data is added to any of the other tables I have referenced. This table contains the ID, the action (so something like 'has uploaded a track.') and the timestamp.

ARTIST TABLE;

```
CREATE TABLE `artists` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`DP` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
UNIQUE KEY `DP` (`DP`),
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `artists_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `members` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

TRACKS

```
CREATE TABLE `tracks` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`track_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`track_ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
UNIQUE KEY `track_ID` (`track_ID`),
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `members` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=111112 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

NEWS

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`article` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
KEY `ID` (`ID`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

STATUS

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(300) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `status_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `artists` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

EVENTS

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`action` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
KEY `ID` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `members` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci COMMENT='This table shows what the artist has done and is used feed'
```

The query I have tried and it failed. This one only references the tracks and events tables. I am not sure how to add the other tables to the query.

```
SELECT
T.url,
T.ID,

E.action,
E.ID,
E.timestamp

FROM tracks T
JOIN events E ON T.ID = E.ID
WHERE T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.'
ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC
```

To answer extremely valid comment, the query is in an AJAX requested page for a news feed. The output will be something along the lines of;

An artist has uploaded a track.
**Track goes here**
**Formatted timestamp here**

---

Another artist has some news.
**News goes here**
**Formatted timestamp here**

---

Hopefully that will give you an idea.

All data by the end of it should be ordered by timestamp. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the output you'd like to see from the events table? For instance, do you want to have all actions listed in a single field, or do you want to have multiple records per ID for each action that belongs to the ID?

Comment: Also, as an aside, is there any reason why the News table is using MyISAM but the rest are InnoDB? It's probably best to stick with one storage engine, and probably best to stay with InnoDB.

Comment: @imm thanks for having a look at this question as well. I have added a quick samples of what it will look like if that's the kind of thing you were after

Comment: @imm Thanks for noticing that, i was having a play around with indexes etc and didn't realized I hadn't changed it back. Always good to have a second pair of eyes!

Comment: what if the same artist has uploaded a track *and* has added some news? Do you want separate lines for both, or do you want them combined into a single entry?

Comment: Yes separate lines for both which probably makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single table with all events in it, and the message that you want to show, I'm confused why you would have to join in any of the other tables---maybe other than your member table, which would give you the user's name. Since you want each event in its own record, there's no need for any kind of aggregation. (Although, if you did want to display a comma-separated list of actions for a user, have a look at [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).)

For example a query like:

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN events.table_name = "tracks" THEN "has uploaded a track."
      WHEN events.table_name = "news" THEN "has some news."
    END AS description
  , events.action
  , DATE_FORMAT(events.when_it_happened, "%a %l%p") AS when_it_happened
  , members.username
  , members.ID
FROM events
INNER JOIN members ON (events.ID = members.ID)
WHERE events.when_it_happened >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
ORDER BY events.when_it_happened DESC
```

Would give you all events that all users performed within the last 5 days; the most recent first.

Comment: You have it confused I think. The events table only has ID action and timestamp. I need to retrieve other information from othe tables according to the action. For example if an artist had uploaded a track then I would need to retrieve the track URL and name from the tracks table as well as the artists name and URL from the artists table

Comment: @nbs189, the information in all those tables seems so similar, why not just dump them into your events table as they happen?

Comment: Less importantly it would destroy the point of those tables. More importantly the columns on the tables have different names. For example, URL in tracks is not present in news. Even more importantly, I will be doing different things with the data that comes out from the tables so I need different column names, which they are.  I would need to put the track URL into jQuery but simply echo the news article